# Select box having different options need to be queried in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, search

I have a select box which more or less looks like this :

```
<select id="select_experience">
       <option value="1,2">1-2</option>
       <option value="3,4">3-4</option>
       <option value="5,6,7,8,9">5-9</option>
       <option value="10,11,12,13,14,15">10-15</option>
       <option value="15+">15+</option>
</select>
```

This is a search filter, so that if I select an option out of this, it will create a condition for querying. I have a column in mysql which shows tutor experiences :

```
tutorid | experience 
  1     |   5 
  2     |   1
  3     |   10
  4     |   3
```

My current query looks like this:

```
$query_tutors = $this->db->get_where("tutor_info", array("tutor_id" => $id, "I need to add that selectbox selected option here."));
```

**My question is :**

Where will I do the `explode` thing? and how will I check for `15+` in that query?

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you stored `select_experience` input to `$id` variable.

You can use following code

```
$this->db->from('tutor_info');
if (strpos($id,'+') !== false)//if 15+
{
    $ranges=explode('+',$id);//get the integer value.You may need to check more to make sure it is intger
    $this->db->where('tutorid >=',$ranges[0]);//only >=15
}
else if (strpos($id,'-') !== false)//if range like 5-9
{
    $ranges=explode('-',$id);
    $this->db->where('tutorid >=',$ranges[0]);//>=5
    $this->db->where('tutorid <=',$ranges[1]);//<=9
}
$query_tutors=$this->db->get();
```

**Note**
This answer is for your first revision where values was like 1-2,3-4,5-9..

Answer (score 0):

in your model, get the selected option

```
$experience_level = $this->input->post("select_experience");
```

This will work only if change the html like this

```
<select name="select_experience" id="select_experience">
   <option value="1,2">1-2</option>
   <option value="3,4">3-4</option>
   <option value="5,6,7,8,9">5-9</option>
   <option value="10,11,12,13,14,15">10-15</option>
   <option value="15+">15+</option>
</select>
```

If not you can either submit the value by Ajax...
Any way get the selected option value to $experience_level

Then do condition check like this

```
if($experience_level !='15+'){
$this->db->where_in("experience", explode(",", $experience_level);
}else{
$this->db->where("experience >", 15);
}
```

Comment: Your answer only is working for the first value. For example if I choose 3-4 and the cell value is 3 then is working. But if the cell value is 4 it's not.

Comment: Can you please post the output of echo $this->db->last_query(); here? 
echo it below the line $this->db->get()